# Program through Task Scheduler using Constant 100% CPU

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, scheduled-tasks, cpu

I have a MS Word Automation C# program that is CPU hungry, basically it loops through records in a DB, opens Word, does a mail merge for the individual record, kills WINWORD.exe and then loops to the next record. When I run the program directly from Command Promtt, it will spike to 100% CPU while doing the mail merge, and then the CPU will drop and I am happy enough with this.

But when I schedule the task through Windows Task Scheduler (Win Server 2008 R2) the CPU spikes to 100% and remains constant and the program bombs out without finishing. Anyone have any ideas as to why there would be differences between running the program through Task Scheduler compared to manually through Command Prompt?

Comment: If it's crashing are there any clues in the logs ? Is it actually doing anything when run through task scheduler ? Can you attach the debugger ?

Comment: Thanks bhs for your quik reply. The code runs fine in visual studio when I attempt to debug, in terms of task schedulerO'm not sure how I would debug this??

Comment: Add logging to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it runs with another user when you schedule it? This can cause problems permissions? With environment variables? With default running folder differences?

Can you write a *very* simple word automation and see if it suffers from the same issue? This will let you know if the problem is the way you run it or what you run.

The comments other people wrote are very correct - you should log and see what causes the trouble.

Also - Killing WINWORD.exe can cause trouble you don't want to get into - like file recovery dialogs. I would recommend closing the document and word properly and wait for winword.exe to exit. Only if that fails kill it, but be ready to handle the trouble.

Vadim.